# InexactError() in imwrite

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia and I cant explain myself where this InexactError() comes from, when I execute the following code:

```
ImBin=rgb2bin(im); # convert image into binary image with own function returns Array{Float64} at the moment
ImBin=round(ImBin); 
ImOut=grayim(ImBin);
imwrite(ImOut,"ImOut.png");
```

I have written another function where it works fine:

```
ImArray=convert(Array{Float64}, ImInput); #ImInput is a BitArray
Im=grayim(ImArray);
imwrite(Im,"Im.png");
```

The error message of the first code block:

```
ERROR: InexactError()
 in _map_a! at /root/.julia/v0.3/Images/src/map.jl:372
 in map! at /root/.julia/v0.3/Images/src/map.jl:364
 in image2wand at /root/.julia/v0.3/Images/src/io.jl:341
 in imwrite at /root/.julia/v0.3/Images/src/io.jl:189
 in main at /home/user/Desktop/julia/Test.jl:35
 in include at ./boot.jl:245
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:128
 in process_options at ./client.jl:285
 in _start at ./client.jl:354
```

Thanks in advance,
Greets clax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be warning you that something about your image is outside the range `0.0 <= x <= 1.0`. You could clamp your image manually, or force it to do it for you by adding the `mapi` keyword:

```
imwrite(ImOut, "ImOut.png", mapi=mapinfo(Clamp, ImOut))
```

If that doesn't fix it, please open an issue over at [Images.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Images.jl), including a complete method for reproducing the error.

Comment: Your suggestion was right. Thanks a lot, it work. Sry for the late reply.